# Prove that: $\nabla (u\cdot u)=2(\nabla u)u$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that

$\nabla (u\cdot u)=2(\nabla u)u$   ; where $u=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}$ smooth enough.

================================================

Calculating I obtain

$(\nabla u)u=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\\ \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\ u_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}+u_2\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\\ u_1\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}+u_2\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}$

and

$\nabla(u\cdot u)=\nabla(u_1^2+u_2^2)=2\begin{bmatrix}u_1\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}+u_2\dfrac{\partial u_{\color{red}2}}{\partial x_{\color{red}1}}\\ u_1\dfrac{\partial u_{\color{red}1}}{\partial x_{\color{red}2}}+u_2\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}$

I'm wrong, but I don't know where is the error.

Answer (score 1):

$$u\cdot u = (u_1,u_2)\cdot (u_1,u_2) = u_1^2+u_2^2 \to \nabla (u\cdot u) =  \nabla(u_1^2+u_2^2) = (2u_1(u_1)_x+2u_2(u_2)_x, 2u_1(u_1)_y+2u_2(u_2)_y)=2\begin{pmatrix} (u_1)_x & (u_2)_x \\ (u_1)_y & (u_2)_y \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2\end{pmatrix}=2(\nabla u)u$$.

Comment: Sorry, but I understand that 

$\nabla u=\begin{pmatrix} (u_1)_x & (u_{\color{red}1})_{\color{red}y} \\ (u_{\color{red}2})_{\color{red}x} & (u_2)_y \end{pmatrix}$


maybe that is my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Using the summing notation, where repeated indices are implied to be summed over, $\nabla (\vec u \cdot \vec u) =\hat x_i \partial_i \left(u_ju_j\right)$.  Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}
\nabla (\vec u \cdot \vec u) &=\hat x_i \partial_i \left(u_ju_j\right) \\
&= \hat x_i 2\partial_i \left(u_j\right)u_j \\
&=2\hat x_i \partial_i \left(u_j\hat x_j\right)\cdot (\hat x_j u_j)  \\
&= 2\nabla(\vec u)\cdot \vec u
\end{align}$$

which was to be shown!

NOTE:  $$2\nabla(\vec u)\cdot \vec u=2\hat x_i \partial_i \left(u_j\hat x_j\right)\cdot (\hat x_j u_j) \ne 2\hat x_j \partial_j \left(u_i\hat x_i\right)\cdot (\hat x_j u_j)=2\vec u \cdot    \nabla(\vec u) $$

Comment: thanks, but I want to know where is my error (in my answerd). Can you tell me where is my error ?

Comment: Yes.  In the first case, application of the $\nabla$ operator  is incorrect.  The first row of the only column is indeed $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$.  But upon application, this partial got distributed in the first column.  Do I get an "up vote" for helping?

Comment: @yemio I hope that you're doing well and staying safe and healthy.  I know that this question/answer was posted more than 5 years ago.  But please feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)

Comment: but I still have my original questions, I don't understand what is wrong :/

Comment: @yemino Well, I thought I had answered this in a comment posted above.  In the first case, application of the $\nabla$ operator is incorrect. The first row of the only column is indeed $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. But upon application, this partial got distributed in the first column.   Does this make sense?

Comment: Note that $$\nabla (\vec u)=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\\ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}&\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}\ne\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\\ \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Note that $$\nabla (\vec u)=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\\ \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}&\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}\ne\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\\ \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}&\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}$$since $$\nabla (\vec u)=\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\right)^T\, \left(u_1,u_2\right)$$In your approach, you transposed this.